# JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow but doesn't show where it originates

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm getting an error and I have no idea why it's happening. I looked into it and I'm understanding that the memory is being filled. The error I'm getting is...

```
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115] JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115] local reference table dump:
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]   Last 10 entries (of 512):
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       511: 0x71552330 java.lang.Class<android.text.SpannableStringBuilder>
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       510: 0x131b2260 java.lang.String ""
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       509: 0x131b1550 java.lang.String "111111111111"
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       508: 0x131b10a0 java.lang.String "111111111111"
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       507: 0x131adbb0 java.lang.String "111111111111"
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       506: 0x131ad700 java.lang.String "111111111111"
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       505: 0x131ad250 java.lang.String "111111111111"
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       504: 0x131abd60 java.lang.String "111111111111"
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       503: 0x131ab8b0 java.lang.String "111111111111"
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       502: 0x131ab400 java.lang.String "111111111111"
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]   Summary:
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]         3 of java.lang.Class (3 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]         1 of java.lang.String[] (3 elements)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115]       508 of java.lang.String (508 unique instances)
[art] art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:115] 
[art] art/runtime/barrier.cc:90] Check failed: count_ == 0 (count_=-1, 0=0) Attempted to destroy barrier with non zero count
[art] art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!
[art] art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]
```

It happens when I click a button which sets off this event and method...

```
doneSampling.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    this.checkFinished();
};

....

skip.CheckedChange += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (barcode.Text.Length <= 0)
    {
        barcode.RequestFocus();
    }

    if ((e.IsChecked == true && barcode.Text.Length > 0) && skipped == false)
    {
        skipped = true;
        SampleState.Instance.storeSessionState(Row,
                        new Sample(tagText, 0, long.Parse(barcodeText),
                        SampleState.Instance.getRowTabState(Row), currentUnit, skip.Checked));

        this.clean();
    }
};
```

....

```
private void checkFinished()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SampleState.Instance.getSamples(Row).Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (SampleState.Instance.getSamples(Row).ElementAt(i).Skipped == true)
            {
                unitText.Text = SampleState.Instance.getSamples(Row).ElementAt(i).Unit.ToString();
                animalTagText.Text = SampleState.Instance.getSamples(Row).ElementAt(i).Tag;
               barcode.Text = SampleState.Instance.getSamples(Row).ElementAt(i).BarCode.ToString();
                rowText.Text = SampleState.Instance.getSamples(Row).ElementAt(i).Row.ToString();

            }
            else if (i == SampleState.Instance.getSamples(Row).Count - 1 && skipped != true)
            {
                this.finshedSampling();
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            Toast.MakeText((SessionActivity)this.Activity, "Seems to have hit the end :/.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

The error doesn't tell me which line is basically causing the issue so I have no idea why it's running out of space. Any help would be reallt appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of your sample `Count`?

Comment: 2. I enter into the sample list dynamically once information is entered. It only happens once I click on a checkbox which skips the current information taking session. I'll throw it up in the question. Thanks for helping.